# how to get god status in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, god

I have setup god and provided script file to load and it working as expected.
i wanted to take status of that god process from my rails application.

I am not able to take god status from my rails controller.

my code

```
require 'god'
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  def status_check
    God::status
  end
end
```

but this gives me error `uninitialized constant HomesController::God`

Please help me to call god status from my web application.

Answer (score 1):

`require 'god'` does not do much without [`$load_god` globally set to `true`](https://github.com/mojombo/god/blob/master/lib/god.rb#L5).

If you for some reason want to load `God` in production Rails, set `$load_god = true` before `require 'god'`.

Please notice, that the productivity penalty might be drastic.